# How to draw Windows 7 taskbar like Shaded Buttons

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2005, windows-7

Windows 7 taskbar buttons are drawn on a shaded background. The color shade somehow reacts on where the mouse is over the button.

I'd like to use such buttons in my application. How can i do that ?

Comment: I think it's basically a simple radial gradient that moves along with the mouse pointer. There is a second gradient involved when the mouse is moving close to the top of the button. Is this what you want to know, are are you rather looking for a ready-to-use taskbar-like button? :)

Comment: I just checked, by the way, at least with Aero enabled the buttons do not appear to be windows, the entire button list is a single window. This means that the buttons are likely drawn manually. UISpy, however, shows the buttons separately (Windows UI Automation).

Comment: Thanks OregonGhost. You are right. The whole Windows 7 taskbar is a single window. This is also the case in XP, though the window class is different there. Thats the same even with the new Ribbons: All ribbons of a Applications window are ONE Window of type "NetUIHWND". Why do we us a windowmanager at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect is called "Color Hot-track". It does not seem that there is a dedicated API for that. There are some notes in a [developer blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2008/11/20/happy-anniversary-windows-on-the-evolution-of-the-taskbar.aspx) about it:

I found some source code from Rudi Grobler though doing a similar thing:

[Make your WPF buttons color hot-track!](http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2009/10/14/make-your-wpf-buttons-color-hot-track.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try

DrawThemeBackground

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773289(VS.85).aspx

Give it the BS_PUSHBUTTON constant.  I've used this in Windows XP to draw the plush blue XP themed controls, but not in Aero, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks although not the solution, this is a great hint. I have 2 or three places were i tried to draw button like objects my own. Using DrawThemeBackground i can get it done by Windows in the original way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they're implemented as shader programs on the GPU. Just a simple program which takes the cursor position, and computes a brightness for each pixel based on the distance from that position.

Comment: If I remember correctly, they work in a VM with non-WDDM drivers, so there should also be a software algorithm.

Comment: They do? I thought they were disabled when Aero Glass is off. Anyway, the algorithm is the same if you do it in software. Just slower.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the new animation api (Some of it exists in Vista, extended in 7) There is no magic style to set, you still need to do the drawing on your own